# Generate random string in a html link

Tags: javascript, html, string, url, random

So I'm trying to make a link where the last part of the url is a random string generated by JavaScript. The Javascript function I have been using is this:

```
 function randomString(length, chars) {
    var result = '';
    for (var i = length; i > 0; --i) result += chars[Math.round(Math.random() * (chars.length - 1))];
    return result;
}
document.write(randomString(6, '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'));
```

How can I use this string inside a url, for example: `<a href="http://mypage.com/random-generated-string">?`

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
var link = document.getElementById("id_of_anchor");
link.href = "http://mypage.com/" + randomString(6, '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ');
```

Answer (score 0):

**Pure JavaScript:**

```
function randomizeHref()
{
    var e = window.event;
    e.preventDefault();

    var url = e.target.href;
    url += randomString(6, '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ');

    location.replace(url);

    return false;
}
```

Then in your HTML:

```
<a href="http://www.mypage.com/" onclick="randomizeHref();">Click here</a>
```

---

**Using jQuery:**

```
function randomizeHref(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();

    var url = this.href;
    url += randomString(6, '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ');

    location.replace(url);

    return false;
}

$(function()
{
    $('a[rel=randomizeHref]').click(randomizeHref);
});
```

Then:

```
<a href="http://www.mypage.com/" rel="randomizeHref">Click here</a>
```

Comment: Hmm, I tried both the jQuery and JavaScript version but none of the seems to send me off the the link. I can click them, but nothing happens.

Comment: Did you check the `console` for errors? what Browser did you check?

Comment: I forgot to close a bracket! Thank you, this method works great!